# Weird TCP re-transmission

Tags: tcp, wireshark, pcap

My question is why a TCP flow make a re-transmission when a network has enough link bandwidth.
For finding a cause, I used a wireshark. I got the below captured at a host side (10.0.0.1)

```
25434 50.968633785 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 TCP 33370 42848 → 50004 [ACK] 
Seq=14063654 Ack=1 Win=29696 Len=33304 TSval=290016 TSecr=290011

25435 50.968637512 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 TCP 31274 42848 → 50004 [PSH, ACK] 
Seq=14096958 Ack=1 Win=29696 Len=31208 TSval=290016 TSecr=290011

25492 50.977183364 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2 TCP 866 [TCP Retransmission] 42848 → 
50004 [PSH, ACK] Seq=14127366 Ack=1 Win=29696 Len=800 TSval=290019 TSecr=290011

25513 50.979382486 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.1 TCP 66 50004 → 42848 [ACK] Seq=1 
Ack=14096958 Win=16776192 Len=0 TSval=290018 TSecr=290016

25514 50.979383087 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.1 TCP 66 50004 → 42848 [ACK] Seq=1 
Ack=14128166 Win=16776192 Len=0 TSval=290018 TSecr=290016

25543 50.981453868 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.1 TCP 78 [TCP Dup ACK 25514#1] 50004 → 
42848 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=14128166 Win=16776192 Len=0 TSval=290019 TSecr=290019 
SLE=14127366 SRE=14128166
```

In summary,

(1) [.1 -> .2 ] SEQ = 14063654, ACK = 1, LEN = 33304

(2) [.1 -> .2 ] SEQ = 14096958, ACK = 1, LEN = 31208

(3) [.1 -> .2 ][Retr] SEQ = 14127366, ACK = 1, LEN = 800

(4) [.2 -> .1 ] SEQ = 1, ACK = 14096958, LEN = 0

(5) [.2 -> .1 ] SEQ = 1, ACK = 14128166, LEN = 0

(6) [.2 -> .1 ] SEQ = 1, ACK = 14128166, LEN = 0, SLE =14127366, SRE=14128166

​

I totally do not know why the re-transmission occur at (3)

I guess the SACK (6) occur due to (3).

As you see, (4), (5) is the ack due to (1), (2) respectively.

I think the re-transmission (3) is not needed.

Could you give me a little hint about the reason of the re-transmission?

Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: I don't trust that the way you got the trace showed you the packets in order. It would be nice to have a trace from a port mirror in a switch rather than from one of the endpoint hosts. It's really weird that it retransmitted 800 bytes of a segment. Also, what kind of a network was this on, with an MTU over 32KiB? Or was there IP fragmentation going on, and this was after reassembly? Also, what hardware offloads were involved?

Comment: @Spiff After seeing your comment, I realized that TSO option at NIC is on.(Actually I did a experiment at mininet-virtual network). Therefore, NIC makes the packets larger than MTU. Maybe 32KB is the window size at that time. After making TSO option off, I find that the original 800 bytes packet was lost and then the packet was re-transmitted. Thank you so much! Could you write the answer for choosing your answer? I appreciate you!

Comment: Thanks @nimdrak, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those ~32KiB TCP segments suggest you may be using TSO/LRO or similar hardware offloads on the host on which you captured the packet trace, so the packet trace may not be truly representative of what occurred "on the wire".

Try disabling all hardware offloads and doing your trace again, or do a trace from a port mirror on a switch to get an independent view of what happened on the wire.